# SQL concat function, combine size and colour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If there is a table called variant

```
id             slug             slug_id
-------        ---------        ----------
1              s                 10
1              m                 10
1              l                 10
1              black             11
1              pink              11
1              ship_us           12
1              ship_uk           12
2              xl                10
2              xxl               10
2              blue              11
2              white             11
```

Result I need in this format:

```
id             variant_slug
--------       ------------
1              1-s-black-ship_us
1              1-s-black-ship_uk
1              1-s-pink-ship_us
1              1-s-pink-ship_uk
1              1-m-black-ship_us
1              1-m-black-ship_uk
1              1-m-pink-ship_us
1              1-m-pink-ship_uk
1              1-l-black-ship_us
1              1-l-black-ship_uk
1              1-l-pink-ship_us
1              1-l-pink-ship_uk
2              2-xl-blue
2              2-xl-white
2              2-xxl-blue
2              2-xxl-white
```

Q: this record is in same variant table. I have almost no experience using UDFs, stored procedures, I need to be done this thing through query. Is this possible without using UDFs, SP's.

Comment: are the type of colors fixed?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a pattern in your data. How would you know which data to concat to which data?

Comment: is there another column in that table that identify the `slug` value as `Size` or `Color` ?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. If you can't explain how to transform the input to the (desired) output then it's hard for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a self-join assuming the length of size<=3.

```
Select A.ID
      ,variant_slug = concat(A.id,'-',A.slug,'-',B.slug)
 from  YourTable A
 Join  YourTable B 
   on A.ID=B.ID 
  and A.slug<>B.slug 
  and len(B.slug)>3 
  and len(A.slug)<=3
```

**Results**

```
ID  variant_slug
1   1-l-black
1   1-l-pink
1   1-m-black
1   1-m-pink
1   1-s-black
1   1-s-pink
2   2-xl-blue
2   2-xl-white
2   2-xxl-blue
2   2-xxl-white
```

Rather than `len()`, you can enumerate the sizes i.e.  `{NOT } IN ('s','m','l','xl','xxl')`

```
Select A.ID
      ,variant_slug = concat(A.id,'-',A.slug,'-',B.slug)
 from  YourTable A
 Join  YourTable B 
   on A.ID=B.ID 
  and A.slug<>B.slug 
  and B.slug NOT IN ('s','m','l','xl','xxl') 
  and A.slug IN ('s','m','l','xl','xxl')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it seems you misunderstood me
I mean if the data is dynamic, how do we handle it
I edited the question to make it easier for you to understand and also apologize for my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `INNER JOIN` by separating the table into two separate tables: `size`, `color` and get the variant data, as given below:

```sql
declare @slug table(id int, slug varchar(100))

insert into @slug values
(1,'s')
,(1,'m')
,(1,'l')
,(1,'black')
,(1,'pink')
,(2,'xl')
,(2,'xxl')
,(2,'blue')
,(2,'white');

SELECT size.id, CONCAT_WS('-',size.id,size.size, color.color) as variant_size
from (select id,slug as size from @slug where slug in ('s','m','l','xl','xxl') ) as size
INNER JOIN (select id,slug as color from @slug where slug NOT in ('s','m','l','xl','xxl') ) as COLOR
on color.id = size.id
```

| id | variant_size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1-s-black |
| 1 | 1-s-pink |
| 1 | 1-m-black |
| 1 | 1-m-pink |
| 1 | 1-l-black |
| 1 | 1-l-pink |
| 2 | 2-xl-blue |
| 2 | 2-xl-white |
| 2 | 2-xxl-blue |
| 2 | 2-xxl-white |

Comment: Thank you for helping me
but what if in the slug column there are more attributes than size, color but the above 2 ids don't have it, what to do?
For example, add a shipping attribute for example

Comment: @SnTS, please post that as a separate question. Modifying question, will lead to confusion for future readers. If current solution is acceptable to you, please mark them as answer. so, it will be helpful for future visitors of the site.